# Signature Does not match while connecting to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've written this simplest code to connect to S3 -

```
String accessKey = "somekey";
String secretKey = "somesecret";

AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
conn.setEndpoint("advenio-ireland.s3.amazonaws.com");

List<Bucket> buckets = conn.listBuckets();
for (Bucket bucket : buckets) {
    System.out.println(bucket.getName() + "\t" +
        StringUtils.fromDate(bucket.getCreationDate()));
}
```

I'm getting below error -

> Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to
>   Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
>   Error Message:    The request signature we calculated does not match
>   the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
>
> HTTP Status Code: 403
>   AWS Error Code:   SignatureDoesNotMatch
>   Error Type:       Client
>   Request ID:       396D5E93F8D827DE

I'm able to connect through S3 browser with the same access key and secret key but through code its not working! I'm using AWS-SDK version 1.8.7.

Please suggest a reason for why the error is occuring.

Comment: I assume you mean the AWS-SDK for Java. (It is not clear from your question text.) Did you try the latest version of the SDK (1.9.37, as far as I can see)? Did you try compiling and running the provided sample — http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/java/ ?

Comment: It was an issue with conn.setEndpoint("advenio-ireland.s3.amazonaws.com"); after I remove this, it worked fine

Comment: maybe you should make this an answer and check it as accepted. I think that would follow the community practice.